# Delete localisation / language button is disabled

Tags: app-store-connect

I am adding a new version of my app and trying to delete some languages that previous versions supported. But the delete button is disabled for me.

My app status is `Prepare for upload`

How do I delete a language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem and realized that it is in fact a bug. But however there is a workaround.

Just use Firefox with the Firebug Plugin, right-click the "Delete" Button and explore the element using Firebug. Within the  Element you will find this element:

```
<div class="modules-dropdown-container locale-delete">
```

Select it, go to the styles tab and remove the attribute "pointer-events: none;". Then you are good to go.

Comment: haha :D I was thinking of something similar. But then my client decided to provide me the translations instead of removing the languages. But I feel what you recommended will work. Going to accept your answer.